# Selecting unique values from self-referencing table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose we have the following data in the table named `My_Tabel`:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║  ID       ║ Person_Name ║ Partner_ID ║ 
╠═══════════╬═════════════╬════════════╬
║  101      ║  John       ║ 3          ║ 
║  100      ║  Miller     ║ 0          ║ 
║  3        ║  Ruby       ║ 101        ║ 
║  180      ║  Jack       ║ 0          ║ 
║  199      ║  George     ║ 65         ║
║  23       ║  Joseph     ║ 0          ║
║  34       ║  Fredrick   ║ 117        ║
║  117      ║  Jinan      ║ 34         ║
║  122      ║  Verena     ║ 0          ║
║  65       ║  Mary       ║ 199        ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Where 0 values in Partner_ID Column indicates that he/she is single.

We need to display partnered persons without repeating or duplication, the desired result should look like:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Person_Name ║ Partner_Name ║ 
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬
║  John       ║  Ruby        ║ 
║  George     ║  Mary        ║
║  Fredrick   ║ Jinan        ║
╚═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

what is the best SQL query that returns the above results?

I'm using this code:

```
SELECT    
  t1.Name, t2.Name          
FROM  My_Tabel t1
INNER JOIN  My_Tabel t2 ON (t2.ID = t1.Partner_ID)
```

but it the returned result is:

```
╔═════════════╦══════════════╗
║ Person_Name ║ Partner_Name ║ 
╠═════════════╬══════════════╬
║  John       ║  Ruby        ║ 
║  Ruby       ║  John        ║
║  George     ║  Mary        ║
║  Mary       ║  George      ║
║  Fredrick   ║  Jinan       ║
║  Jinan      ║  Fredrick    ║   
╚═════════════╩══════════════╝
```

how the SQL statement should be updated (or replaced with another) to get the desired results?

Comment: What [RDBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system)?

Comment: SQL Server @MaciejLos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a condition to get one side of each pair:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t2.Name          
FROM My_Table t1 INNER JOIN
     My_Table t2
     ON (t2.ID = t1.Partner_ID)
WHERE t1.ID < t2.ID;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm still a beginner :)  could you please briefly explain what changes happened in the logic of the statement when adding the condition: `WHERE t1.ID < t2.ID`

Comment: @EzzedeenSaghier . . . You want no repeats, so this orders the results so `t1.id` is always less than `t2.id`.  That means that you don't get the bigger value first.